# Runtime error when trying to run a Django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, runtime, web-development-server

I'm trying to run a django project I worked on a while ago. Most of what I did I've forgotten. I get a run time error when launching the project. I only just imported these files over to my computer. I'm wondering if i'm missing any dependencies? It's been a very long time since I've programmed in django or python. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop\django_project>python manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1370, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1176, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'C:\Users\Shadow\Desktop\django_project>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1370, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1176, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Heres my manage.py code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: please provide your source code while asking questions.

Comment: The key part of the error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'` - it looks as if you haven't run `pip install crispy-forms`. Once you've done that, you might get similar errors for other dependencies. If your project had a `requirements.txt` or a pipenv file, then make sure you have installed all the requirements. Finally, note that Python 3.8 was released recently, it might be easier to get the project running with the same versions that you used before, then upgrade Python.

Comment: @Shadow_S since manage.py script is generated automatically by Django when you start a new project via command prompt, it does not contain any errors, unless you changed it. So there is no need to share its code. If you are new to Django, I suggest you to learn how to read the error traceback https://realpython.com/python-traceback/ It will save you a lot of time.